# Wordpress Custom Meta Box Not Showing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

Trying to add meta boxes to my admin and found a code here to make them. Made some changes to the code, applied it to my site and the meta boxes are not showing at all, on any post or page types. Code below:

```
add_action('admin_init');

function admin_init() {
    add_meta_box("credits_meta", "Mixtape Info", "credits_meta", "mixtape", "normal", "low");
}

function credits_meta() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $dj = $custom["DJ"][0];
    $embed = $custom["embed code"][0];
    $tracklisting = $custom["tracklisting"][0];
    ?>;
    <label>DJ:</label>
    <input name="DJ" value="<?php echo $dj; ?>"/>
    <p><label>Embed:</label><br />
    <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="embed code"><?php echo $embed; ?></textarea></p>
    <p&><label>Tracklisting:</label><br />
    <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="tracklisting"><?php echo $tracklisting; ?></textarea></p>
    <?php
```

}

Is it something obvious I'm missing? I copied and pasted the example in the link and got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function credits_meta() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $dj = "a";
    $embed = "b";
    $tracklisting = "c";
    ?>
    <label>DJ:</label>
    <input name="DJ" value="<?php echo $dj; ?>"/>
    <p><label>Embed:</label><br />
    <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="embed code"><?php echo $embed; ?></textarea></p>
    <p&><label>Tracklisting:</label><br />
    <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="tracklisting"><?php echo $tracklisting; ?></textarea></p>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_action('admin_init');` This is wrong.

`add_action` expects the first argument to be the function hook, and the 2nd argument to be the function to execute when the hook is called, such as:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_init');
```

But even that's wrong, because you're going to get an error about trying to redeclare a previously declared function, so instead, it should be something like

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin_init');
```

Where `my` is the namespace of your application.

Or use classes. This might exist in a file called `my_class.php`

```
class my_class {
    public function my_admin_init(){
        //do work
    }
}
```

Require this file in your `functions.php`

```
require_once('path/to/my_class.php');
```

Instantiate the class

```
$my_class = new my_class;
```

Now call the function on `admin_init`

```
add_action('admin_init', array($my_class, 'my_admin_init'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this for two days -  I fixed the problem by adding ...

wp_nonce_field( basename( **FILE** ), 'your_plugin_name_nonce' );

... to my form in my metabox.